# Is possible in on click function in jQuery wait for ajax complete and then do some code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want show modal after ajax is complete, here is my code:

```
$('.mymodalbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    modalWindow = $(this).attr('data-target');
    // alert(modalWindow);
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
         //0 === $.active
        $(modalWindow).modal('show');

    });

});
```

It is possible to do that? Now modal show after every ajax complete.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ajaxComplete()` method of `ajax` request,which  registers a handler to be called when `Ajax` request is **completed**.

Read more [here.](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

Use complete event when your ajax call completed.

```
$('.mymodalbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    modalWindow = $(this).attr('data-target');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'your_url',
        success: function (responseData, textStatus) {

        },
        complete: function (textStatus) {
            $(modalWindow).modal('show');
        },
        error: function (responseData)
        {

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the way you're doing an ajax call, but I've been able to do it with the post super global

$_post(phpfile.php, `$_post(phpfile.php, {variables to send}, function)` you can use data as a parameter for the function and it will be anything that PHP echoes including error messages

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for inspiration finally I do it this way.

global variable:

```
window.modal = "";
```

on click function:

```
$('.mymodalbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    modalWindow = $(this).attr('data-target');     
    window.modal = modalWindow;   

});
```

and ajax complete:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
       if(window.modal != ""){
           $(window.modal).modal('show');
           window.modal = "";
       }    
});
```

Hope it is allright :-)

Comment: But if you have multiple ajax request in your page then `$(document).ajaxComplete({})` fired for each ajax call.

Comment: I know, but it´s only one if statement so delay will be minimal.

Answer (score -1):

try to use setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#mymodal').modal('show');
},4000);
```

Comment: The original OP asked open a modal window when ajax completed. Not after some particular amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. You can use [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) or [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) or in [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)